# Name of functions that are the discrete sum of a periodic discrete function

Tags: terminology, periodic-functions

Research I am currently engaged in involves the usage of discrete functions of the following form.

Let $a$ be a finite sequence of integers with length $n$ with $a^\infty = a \circ a \circ \dots$ being $a$ cycled infinitely. Define $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ with $f(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^x a^\infty_i = \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor (\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i) + \sum_{i=1}^{x \bmod n} a_i$.

Example with $a = \langle 2, 3, 0, 5 \rangle$:

$f(0) = 0$ $f(1) = 2$ $f(2) = 5$ $f(10) = 10 * 2 + 2 + 3 = 25$

Hence, the functions are discrete and have a periodic increase pattern, which causes
them to be decomposable into a linear and a non-linear component. Furthermore, the function may be extended to negative integers, by reversing the sum and inverting the sign of the sequence. It seems like a relatively common form of function, but I was unable to find a precise term that denotes them, which makes finding related resources difficult. Thus, my question is whether there is a common term for these kinds of functions.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580208/name-of-functions-that-are-the-discrete-sum-of-a-periodic-discrete-function

Comment: $\omega^{<\omega}$ is often used to indicate sequences of finitely many natural numbers so you might have something like $(\omega^{<\omega})^{<\omega}$ but I don't know of a name for this.